# Saving DataURL to jpg

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-url

I have the following code that turns an image file(jpg/png) to data url. Once cropping has been done, I can generate a rendered image, but it is saved as png. I need to be able to save the data url as a jpg.

```
renderButton.click(function (event) {
var dataUrl;

imgly.renderToDataURL("png", { size: "1280" }, function (err, dataUrl) {

var image = $("<img><br>").attr({
    src: dataUrl
  });

  image.appendTo($(".result"))
  $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            image.remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    $button.appendTo($(".result"));;

    });
});
```

Changing `"png"` to `"jpg"` in the renderToDataURL line has no affect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change your call to

```
imgly.renderToDataURL("image/jpeg", { size: "1280" }, function (err, dataUrl)
```

how you can read from source code

```
renderToDataURL: (format, options={}, callback) ->
    if typeof options is "function"
      callback = options
      options = {}

@photoProcessor.renderImage options, (err, imageData) =>
      canvas = Utils.newCanvasFromImageData imageData
      callback null, canvas.toDataURL(format)
```

where `format` is the image format, the `canvas.toDataURL(format)` is the responsible of data translation

The problem was the MIME Type, how you can read from [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110405/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl)

> When the toDataURL(type) method is called with one or more arguments,
>   it must return a data: URL containing a representation of the image in
>   the format given by type. The possible values are MIME types with no
>   parameters, for example image/png, image/jpeg, or even maybe
>   image/svg+xml if the implementation actually keeps enough information
>   to reliably render an SVG image from the canvas.

**EDIT**

```
renderButton.click(function (event) {
var dataUrl;

imgly.renderToDataURL("image/jpeg", { size: "1280" }, function (err, dataUrl) {

var image = $("<img><br>").attr({
    src: dataUrl
  });

  image.appendTo($(".result"))
  $button = $('<button class="btn btn-default remove">')
        .text('Remove')
        .on('click', function () {
            image.remove();
            $(this).remove();
            return false;
        });
    $button.appendTo($(".result"));;

    });
});
```

this should work

Answer (score -1):

`DataURL` is just a string, so you can replace the "png" with "jpeg"

```js
const jpegImg = pngImg.replace("png", "jpeg")
```